# saving form input as a join table entry in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a form for creating an `Event`, within which I want one of the dropdown menus populated with instances of `Artist`. Whatever the user chooses needs to be saved as instances of a `EventArtist` join table. This joint table has two columns: `artist_id` and `event_id`.

here is a sketch of erb form:

```
<%= form_for :event, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(
    "event.artist",
    options_from_collection_for_select(Artist.all, "id", "name")
  ) -%> <br />
  <%= f.submit "Create" %><br />
<% end %>
```

`EventArtist` model:

```
class EventArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

As it is right now, there is nothing inside the `new` definition of events_controller.

In the initial seed file, this works, how to implement something like this in an erb form?

```
artist = Artist.create(name: "name", bio: "bio")

event = Event.create(name: "event name",
                     date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'),
                     venue_id: venue.id,
                     description: "desc")

event.artists << artist
```

Comment: You can use `nested_form` to do this.

Comment: Ryan Bates' gem? it hasn't been maintained in like three years. isn't there a relatively simple to do this without any gems?

Comment: `nested_form` is a rail feature and can be used without any gem, the gem provides some extra features. There is one more gem which I know `cocoon` you can try that too.